# How do I style a core-overlay?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, core-elements

I'm going crazy here. I thought I had a handle on Polymer styling, but alas.

I've got:

```
<my-app>
  <sign-in>
    <core-overlay>
```

In sign_in.css I style:

```
core-overlay {
  background: red;
}
```

But it doesn't work!

My sign_in.html is:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../../../../../packages/core_elements/core_overlay.html">
<polymer-element name="sign-in">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sign_in.css">
    <core-overlay id="overlay" class="overlay" layered backdrop opened="false" transition="core-transition-center">
      <span id="message">Please sign in to comment.</span>
      <button class="signin-btn" id="facebook-signin" on-click="{{signInWithFacebook}}">Sign in with Facebook</button>
    </core-overlay>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="sign_in.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Which element do you want to style and where do you want to put the style tag?

Comment: As I said in the post, I am styling core-overlay, and the styles are in sign_in.css (which is the CSS for the sign-in element which contains the core-overlay element that I'm trying to style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backdrop and core-overlay elements are created dynamically as child of `<body>`. To style it you add the following css to your entry page CSS

#### backdrop

```css
<style>
  body div.core-overlay-backdrop {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

#### overlay

```css
  * /deep/ core-overlay {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 13px;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: green;
     padding:30px 42px;
     outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   }
```

The overlay css is copied from https://github.com/Polymer/core-overlay/blob/master/demo.html#L38-L49.
The core-overlay demo uses a custom Polymer element `x-dialog` to encapsulate the core-overlay and the CSS.

Comment: I'm not trying to style the backdrop, rather the overlay itself (i.e. the thing that's on top of the backdrop) and I thought I could simply reference the core-overlay, but I guess you're right in that I have to get in there at the specific child element since there's more going on in there. I'll look into it.

Comment: I thought you mean the backdrop. You could try to enclose the content of the overlay (span and button) in a `<div id="someid"> your content</div>` and set the background for `#someid { background: red; }`